Why does the approxes variable of a custom eval_metric with catboost for binary classification contain negative values?
In order to create a personal evaluation function with catboost for binary classification, I used the example mentioned here:  How to create custom eval metric for catboost?
However, I have negative values in the "approxes" array as input to the evaluate function and none greater than 0.5, so when we transform this initial array into an integer array with "expit(y_pred).astype(int)", all values are 0, and this for all iterations.
I don't understand why I have negative values when I'm on a binary classification.
When I use the "F:beta" evaluation function (or others), it works properly, and learning takes place as I expect.
Or is it a misunderstanding on my part of how things normally work?
Thank you in advance for your feedback.
I ran my program in debug mode and ran statistics on the values in the "approxes" array provided as input to the "evaluate" function.
But the maximum value obtained is 0.25 and the min value goes down to -1.25.
I'm expecting values between 0 and 1.

I solved my problem after more research.
I'll post the answer if someone encounters the same problem instead of deleting my question.
It was a misinterpretation of the approxes content on my part. It's normal to have negative values in approxes. You need to apply a sigmoid (with expit or manually) it to switch to a value between 0 and 1. The examples in the link I've provided don't seem to work. But it's OK for me now.
